# Setting Row Height At cellForRowAtIndexPath For Different Row Heights

Tags: ios, tableview

Tableview has three types of custom cells with dynamic height. I want to set the row height using like `tableView.rowHeight = 100` in `cellForRowAtIndex()` method.

Is this appropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Define auto layout constraints for your prototype cell
2.Specify the estimatedRowHeight of your table view
3.Set the rowHeight of your table view to UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Do these code in viewDidLoad

tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 68.0(actual height of your prototype cell)

tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimens

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not how you need to do it. Never make any attempt to set any table attributes inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. Just create and return a cell.

If your cells have varying heights, simply implement the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method and return the appropriate height for a given indexPath.

If all rows have the same height, then set the table view's `rowHeight` property in `viewDidLoad` or other appropriate place.